# manage a sequence in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a DB  table with id as primary key.
In the object I have define the colomn getter using @Id
When the user creates a new row it does assign it a new Id.
but it also assign a new id to the old object.

thus, 
when I iterate a list using

```
for(){
    session.save(myO);
}
```

I get new rows in the db for the new elements but also new rows for the old ekements. 
Any assistance? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#save%28java.lang.Object%29) says:

> Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated
>   identifier.

You should call `save` on an existing, detached instance. `save` is to persist a new entity. Use `saveOrUpdate` or `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

first create sequence in database like this given below

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_MFILTERGROUP MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20;

<class name="example.FilterGroup" table="FILTERGROUP">

<id name="id">

generator class="sequence">

<param name="sequence">   SEQ_MFILTERGROUP  </param>

</generator>

</id>

</class>